# How to set an object to nil in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures

I'm implementing a simple Stack in Swift. I ran into an unexpected behavior while writing pop() and I'm hoping someone can explain why this is happening.

I wrote my original pop function like this:

```
class func pop(inout head : Node)->Node? {
    var currentNode : Node? = head

    while currentNode!.next != nil {
        currentNode = currentNode!.next!
    }

    var lastNode = currentNode
    currentNode = nil
    return lastNode
}
```

Basically, I'm finding the tail of my linked list and setting that object to nil. However, the item is retained, as you can see in this console output:

> //traversing the initial list
>
> 10 11 12 13 14
>
> popped: 14
>
> //list after popping
>
> 10 11 12 13 14

As you can see, 14 is not removed, though it is returned by the pop() function correctly.

Now, my second thought was to set the previous node's next pointer to nil, so I edited the above function to read like this:

```
class func pop(inout head : Node)->Node? {
    var currentNode : Node? = head
    var previousNode : Node = head

    while currentNode!.next != nil {
        previousNode = currentNode!
        currentNode = currentNode!.next!
    }

    var lastNode = currentNode
    previousNode.next = nil
    currentNode = nil
    return lastNode
}
```

This prints out the expected output to the console like this:

> //traversing the initial list
>
> 10 11 12 13 14
>
> popped: 14
>
> //list after popping
>
> 10 11 12 13

**My question is this:**

Shouldn't setting currentNode to nil mean that previousNode.next is now pointing to nil? Why do I have to explicitly set previousNode.next = nil
?

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

**SOLUTION:**

Here is the solution I came to with

```
class func pop(inout head : Node?)->Node? {
var currentNode : Node? = head
var previousNode : Node? = head

if currentNode?.next == nil {
    var lastNode = currentNode
    head = nil
    return lastNode

}

while currentNode!.next != nil {
    previousNode = currentNode!
    currentNode = currentNode!.next!
}

var lastNode = currentNode
previousNode!.next = nil
return lastNode
}
```

I needed to treat the last case differently and set head to nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does setting `currentNode` to `nil` not delete the thing it's pointing to? Let me try to use an analogy: Imagine that a variable (if it's an instance of a class) is kind of like a finger. You can use it to point at things. But pointing your finger at a tree, then cutting off your finger, won't cut down the tree.

In the real world, pointers are pointing to memory. When you set a pointer to null, you are not destroying whatever it was pointing to. However, if you set all pointers to an object to null, you have no more way of accessing it and it is effectively lost. (Also ARC or GarbageCollection are gonna come around and actually remove the object from memory, but that's a different story).

Answer (score 0):

```
class func pop(inout head : Node)->Node? {
    var currentNode : Node? = head
    // ...
    currentNode = nil
    // ...
    return lastNode
}
```

> Shouldn't setting currentNode to nil mean that previousNode.next is now pointing to nil

`currentNode` is a *variable*. It has a name and a value. Think of it as a named shoebox. It has something inside it (the value), and can only have *one* thing inside it at a time. At first, it has `head` inside it. Then, when you say `currentNode = nil`, you *remove* `head` from the shoebox and put `nil` inside the shoebox instead. And that is all you do.

(Now, you may be thinking: but what about the fact that `head` is an `inout` parameter? Shouldn't this mean that changes reflect back out to a reference outside this function? Okay, but that's `head`. In your initial attempt, you didn't set `head` to nil! You set `currentNode` to nil.)

Comment: I think if you see the answer I came up with you'll see why I needed to set head to inout. I just wasn't using it correctly initially

Comment: Okay, let me delete that part from my answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "Shouldn't setting currentNode to nil mean that previousNode.next is now pointing to nil?"

The answer is no. currentNode is a variable that points to a node object. It does not point to the the nextNode pointer in the previous node. Changing a local variable currentNode has no effect on the previous node.